# How can i get the steps from a specific failed scenario outline example in cucumber

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I want to trigger an email with the failed steps from a ,failing scenario outline feature file.

I need the java code which gives me the steps starting from Given , till the failing step definition.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create an After hook that gets control after a failure to gain access to the Scenario object.

```
@After
public void myAfterHook(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        System.out.println("***>> Scenario '" + scenario.getName() + "' failed at line(s) " + scenario.getLines() + " with status '" + scenario.getStatus() + "');
    }
}
```

You can use the Scenario object to get

- the name of the failing scenario, and
- the line(s) in the feature file of the Scenario. Scenarios from Scenario Outlines return both the line of the example row the the line of the scenario outline.

You then use the line number(s) to refer back to the failing step in the feature file.